# How to add health checks to .Net core Background service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, servicebus, background-service, health-check

I am having a .net core 2.1 Background service application which is subscribed to a queue in Microsoft Azure Service bus. It has some logic and it calls to an api over http. I would like to create a health check for this service. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Official HealthCheck premiere was in 2.2:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/

Health checks in ASP.NET Core 2.2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2

For 5.0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If you have to stay on 2.1 than I suggest to create a special endpoint for it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me https://dzone.com/articles/monitoring-health-of-aspnet-core-background-servic

It refers to use TCP probes